# How to align a picture to the right border of the container

Tags: css, image, alignment

I want the first picture to be aligned to the right bored of the black div, but I can't move the picture "Char" from where it is.

http://www.charlestonshop.it/homepageteo.html

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
  html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

div#container {
    height:100%;
}
div#container div {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}

div#container div#left {
    /* background-image:url('http://www.charlestonshop.it/charback9.jpg');*/
    background-position: right;
background-color: black;
}
div#container div#right {
   /* background-image:url('http://www.charlestonshop.it/charback10.jpg');*/
    background-position: left;
background-color: white;
}

.charleft img{
        max-width:100% !important;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
    }

    .charright img{
            max-width:100% !important;
            height:auto;
            display:block;
                        float:right;
        }

</style>
```

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your website. Here's why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 3):

Add the below to your css, if you already have rules in place- add the additional styles as outline below:

```
#left{
  position:relative; /* have a reference point for child positioning */
}

.charleft img{
  position:absolute; /* position absolutely */
  right:0; /* position on the right hand side of the parent, #left */
}
```

The benefit of this as opposed to using `float`, is you wont have to either clear the float, or accommodate for any changes it may later inflict on your layout.

Comment: always use float as a last resort, this is way better

Comment: this works, but when you resize the browser it doesn't react properly. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add float: right to .charleft div which contains the image

```
.charleft{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy to do, just add this to your css code.

```
#left > .charleft{
    float: right;
}
```

That's all.